# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Hola buenas estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion con realtime database, pero da un error que no consigo solucionar, es el siguiente:

`"Can't convert object of type java.lang.String"`

he intentado poner en modelo un toString, pero sigue sin funcionar.
Este codigo es reutilizado con otros proyecto que funcionaban bien, pero en este no funciona.

Esta es la actividad

```
public class EpisodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Datos_Episodios> listaEpisodios;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference dataBase;
AdapterEpisodio adapterEpisodio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_episode);

    listaEpisodios = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleEpisodio);
    dataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Series").child("Miraculous")
                                                .child("Tempordas").child("Temporada 1");
    adapterEpisodio = new AdapterEpisodio(listaEpisodios, this);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterEpisodio);

    dataBase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Toast.makeText(EpisodeActivity.this, "Dato si exixte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String titulo = ds.child("titulo").getValue(String.class);
                    String uriImg = ds.child("uriImg").getValue(String.class);
                    String videLink = ds.child("videoLink").getValue(String.class);
                    Datos_Episodios datos = new Datos_Episodios(titulo,uriImg,videLink);
                    
                    listaEpisodios.add(datos);

                }
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(EpisodeActivity.this, "Dato no exixte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

}

he intentado poner en modelo un toString, pero sigue sin funcionar.
Este codigo es reutilizado con otros proyecto que funcionaban bien, pero en este no funciona.

La base de datos [image: La base de datos]

Edit:
He logrado arreglar ese error agregando un constructor, gracias @Benito-B , pero el problema es que no obtiene los datos del todo, ya que luego dan valores null

Comment: Las clases en Java ***JAMÁS*** llevan snakee_case, van en PascalCase, y las variables se escriben en camelCase, que viene a ser lo mismo pero la primera inicial siempre es minúscula. Si respetas las reglas será más fácil que todos entendamos el código cuando lo compartes, de lo contrario, se hace mucho más difícil seguir el flujo si no sé si lo que estás usando es una variable, un método o una clase con métodos estáticos...

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, tienes un constructor con los parámetros o, al menos, setters? Porque si no tienes constructor ni setters, es posible que no pueda asignarlo, no estoy seguro. De todas maneras, poder ver lo que tienes guardado en firebase ayudaría, puesto que nos dices que falla al mapear los datos a tu clase.... pero no podemos ver qué son o como están guardados esos datos!

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido. intentare hacer el código mas legible.  En cuanto a tu pregunta, no tengo ni setter ni constructor solo tengo getters

Comment: En el adapter lo unico q hago es `Datos_Episodios datosE = listE.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(datosE.getUriImg()).into(holder.ImagenPortada);
        holder.titulo.setText(datosE.getTitulo());`

Comment: Si solo tienes getters, cómo monta tu objeto en esta línea: `ds.getValue(Datos_Episodios.class)`?? Quiero decir... si no tienes ni constructor, ni setters... cómo va a asignar las variables?? Prueba a ponerle un constructor con los parámetros correctos a ver si eso lo arregla

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, pero creo q el problema no esta ahí, por que sustituí la lineal `ds.getValue(Datos_Episodios.class)` por esta `String titulo = ds.child("titulo").getValue().toString();` para comprobar si el problema estaba en el adapter o en el modelo. Pero el error es el mismo

Comment: Perdon por la ignorancia pero como muestro esos datos, porcierto probe lo q me dijistes, de crear un constructor. El problema que tengo ahora es q obtengo los datos pero luego los pierdo. Es decir tengo los datos, pero luego me da **valor null**

Comment: No reutilices preguntas para múltiples dudas... Y menos en los comentarios!! Usa el botón de [edit]! Nadie va a ponerse a leer todos estos comentarios para poder responderte... especialmente cuando lo primero que te dije era precisamente la respuesta que necesitabas!

Comment: Perdon es que soy nuevo en esto, ya he editado el codigo de arriba, por si me he dejado algo

Comment: @Benito-B Deberías tratár un poquiiito mejor a los nuevos usuarios, ser mas tolerante y respetuoso con ellos, ya que hasta ahora van entrando y se estan adaptando :(

Comment: @Juantro17 gracias, ya logre solucionarlo gracias Benito-B, el tenia razón la solución me la dio al principio. El problema ya esta resuelto. Ahora... ¿como doy por terminado esto

Comment: Firebase se creó para facilitar las cosas, no para complicarlas. Si tú diseñas correctamente tu objeto, asignándole al menos un método constructor vacío y setter y getter para cada miembro del objeto, luego podrás llenar instancias del objeto haciendo esto: `Datos_Episodios datos = ds.getValue(Datos_Episodios.class);` Es decir, no necesitas obtener cada propiedad a mano para pasarla luego al constructor de la clase. Con esta sola llamada ya tendrás una instancia de `Datos_Episodios` con los datos. Dado que estás empezando al parecer, considera las sugerencias de @Benito-B sobre ...

Comment: ... *convención de nombres*. Y considera también revisar el LogCat. Por ejemplo, cuando tienes fallos mapeando clases de Firebase, el LogCat te lo dirá, y si tienes propiedades mal definidas o te faltan *setters* también te dirá algo como *No se encontró setter para la propiedad tal*. Pues eso, el LogCat es un gran aliado que te ayudará a depurar tu código y ganarás horas encontrando errores eficazmente. El LogCat, por si no lo sabes, es una de las pestañas que aparecen en la parte inferior de Android Studio y hay varios niveles de depuración, cada uno empezando por un letra: `d, i, w, e`  etc

Comment: yo tenia esa linea puesta `Datos_Episodios datos = ds.getValue(Datos_Episodios.class);` ,pero me daba el error `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String` por eso busque otra alternativa, pero gracias por la sugerencia.